# Will it create any critical problems if one always uses ''sudo poweroff"?

Tags: shutdown

Always I have to use `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown -h now` to shut down my PC because the "Shut down" button is not working. According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202108/will-it-create-any-critical-problems-if-one-always-uses-shutdown-h-now) `sudo shutdown -h now` is safe. But what about `sudo poweroff`? Moreover, would you recomend to use `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown -h now`? I'm using 12.04.

Comment: A better question would be 'How to get my Shut Down button to work?, otherwise it  might just be marked as a duplicate of your linked question.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64995/what-is-the-difference-between-shutdown-and-poweroff-commands) for an explanation of the differences between `shutdown` and `poweroff`.

As you can see, in your situation `poweroff` is essentially just invoking `shutdown`.  These are both safe (if you've saved important data and whatnot), SIGTERM (which tells processes to gracefully exit) is sent a few seconds before SIGKILL so that there shouldn't be any corruption.

Pressing the "Shut Down" button probably just calls one of these utilities.  You should probably figure out why that's not working.